# Sorting strings into dictionary, where initial char is the key and the value is a list of all lines starting with that char

Tags: python, list, dictionary

**Situation:** AHLTA, an electronic medical record, exports GUI templates as text. I'm building a template editor and need to import the text file. Each line represents a single GUI element and starts with a number identifying its parent tab in the GUI. The order of the lines is unimportant. I'm using Python 3.

Example (*theFile*):

```
1,550,57,730,77,0,32770," |||||||0|0||0|0|||0|||0|0|1|0|0|0|||","F=TimesNewRoman|C=8421504|T=T","Last updated: 2017-05-18"
0,743,4,823,48,0,16384," |||||||0|0||0|0|||0|||0|0|0|0|0|0|||","F=Arial|O=5|B=T","TSWF Navigator:<formLinkInfo><version>1.1</version><templateName>TSWF-Navigator</templateName><templateId>2238487</templateId><templateOwnerName>Department of Defense</templateOwnerName><templateOwnerNcid>33962</templateOwnerNcid></formLinkInfo>"
0,828,4,907,24,0,16384," |||||||0|0||0|0|||0|||0|0|0|0|0|0|||","O=5","CORE:<formLinkInfo><version>1.1</version><templateName>TSWF-CORE</templateName><templateId>1995726</templateId><templateOwnerName>Department of Defense</templateOwnerName><templateOwnerNcid>33962</templateOwnerNcid></formLinkInfo>"
2,25,791,370,811,297285,8961," | || ||||19|80|YCN|0|0|Y|N|0|||0|0|5|0|0|0|||","F=Arial|T=T","Responds to affection~ (by 4 months)"
2,25,871,370,891,297287,8961," | || ||||19|80|YCN|0|0|Y|N|0|||0|0|5|0|0|0|||","F=Arial|T=T","Indicates pleasure and displeasure~ (by 4 months)"
```

**My Goal:** I want a dictionary of lists, where the keys correspond to the GUI tab number and the list contains all the lines starting with that number.

Example:

```
0: 
0,743,4,823,48,0,16384," |||||||0|0||0|0|||0|||0|0|0|0|0|0|||","F=Arial|O=5|B=T","TSWF Navigator:<formLinkInfo><version>1.1</version><templateName>TSWF-Navigator</templateName><templateId>2238487</templateId><templateOwnerName>Department of Defense</templateOwnerName><templateOwnerNcid>33962</templateOwnerNcid></formLinkInfo>"
0,828,4,907,24,0,16384," |||||||0|0||0|0|||0|||0|0|0|0|0|0|||","O=5","CORE:<formLinkInfo><version>1.1</version><templateName>TSWF-CORE</templateName><templateId>1995726</templateId><templateOwnerName>Department of Defense</templateOwnerName><templateOwnerNcid>33962</templateOwnerNcid></formLinkInfo>"

1:
1,550,57,730,77,0,32770," |||||||0|0||0|0|||0|||0|0|1|0|0|0|||","F=TimesNewRoman|C=8421504|T=T","Last updated: 2017-05-18"

2:
2,25,791,370,811,297285,8961," | || ||||19|80|YCN|0|0|Y|N|0|||0|0|5|0|0|0|||","F=Arial|T=T","Responds to affection~ (by 4 months)"
2,25,871,370,891,297287,8961," | || ||||19|80|YCN|0|0|Y|N|0|||0|0|5|0|0|0|||","F=Arial|T=T","Indicates pleasure and displeasure~ (by 4 months)"
```

**The Problem:** I can't create the lists ahead of time because I don't know how many tabs there are prior to reading the file. I tried looping through the file for each tab, gathering that tab's items in a temporary list, and then adding the list to the dictionary before moving on to the next tab. Sample data shortened for simplicity:

```
theFile = ['1,550,57,730,77', '0,743,4,823,48', '0,828,4,907,24', '2,25,791,370,811', '2,25,871,370,891']
tabCount = 3  # for this example; normally pulled from file header

sortedLines = dict()
for i in range(tabCount):
    tempList = []
    for line in theFile:
        tempList.append(line)
    sortedLines.update({tabCount: tempList})
    tempList.clear()

print('Dict: ', sortedLines)
for k, v in sortedLines.items():
    print('Pair: ' + str(k) + ': ' + '[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, v)))
```

This seems to loop appropriately, but I end up with a single empty pair:

```
{3: []}
3: []
```

**Summary:** How can I create a dictionary of lists when the number of lists is known only at runtime?

Comment: Instead of writing "blah blah" make sure your question is properly formatted so we don't get a seizure while reading it.

Comment: Can you also show a Sample output?

Comment: to @cosinepenguine 's point specifically what code you currently have, what output you're getting and what your desired output is would be the most beneficial to the community in assisting you :-)

Comment: Apologies for the blah blah; had a browser error and it wasn't previewing the text!

Comment: Is it possible to get the downvote removed?

Comment: @pediatrictactic re: downvote removal. The downvoter has to come back and remove it. On another note have you peeked at the answer below? I believe it handles your issue. With python you don't have to define sizes when creating your variables. Lists and dictionaries act more like linked lists and hash maps than arrays from statically typed languages :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def main():
    # I'm assuming you can get this far...
    lines = [
        '1,some stuff 1',
        '2,some stuff 2,more stuff',
        '2,some stuff 4,candy,bacon',
        '3,some stuff 3,this,is,horrible...'
    ]

    # Something to hold your parsed data
    data = {}

    # Iterate over each line of your file
    for line in lines:

        # Split the data apart on comma per your example data
        parts = line.split(',')

        # denote the key is the first part of the split data
        key = parts[0]
        if key not in data:
            # Since there could be multiple values per key we need to keep a
            # list of mapped values
            data[key] = []

        # put the "other data" into the list
        index_of_sep = line.find(',')
        data[key].append(line[index_of_sep+1:])

    # You probably want to return here. I'm printing so you can see the result
    print(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Result**

```
C:\Python35\python.exe C:/Users/Frito/GitSource/sandbox/sample.py
{'3': ['some stuff 3,this,is,horrible...'], '1': ['some stuff 1'], '2': ['some stuff 2,more stuff', 'some stuff 4,candy,bacon']}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Here I have the key as a string. If you really need it to be a numeric type there are plenty of answers here on SO as to how to do that :-)

Comment: Frito, thank you. I'm amazed you figured out what I wanted from early-posting-accident!

Comment: Ha, no problem. Glad that helped! Thanks for accepting the answer :-D